# What's the name of this movie with a sandman?

Tags: urusei-yatsura

It was English dubbed, and I remember seeing it on some anime channel around 2008. It involved a short, fat character with weird teeth creating dreams. I think the main characters called him a sandman. The one thing I remember well was the main characters flying into space from earth after weird stuff happened. They discover the earth is shaped oddly. It is flat and looks like a city being held up by giant statues of people. They seemed to recognize the statues. The sandman character mentioned something about creating a pure dream from the mind of an individual girl in the main cast. This sandman seemed to be an antagonist. Sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: Are you sure it was a movie and not a series?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it was a movie, but it could be a series. I don't remember any intro songs, but I didn't see the whole thing. It could be a series.

Comment: Doesn't sound familiar at all. Hmm, hard one. So the main characters, they flew to space? Did they stay there? Also, if you say main characters, how many were they? Mostely male / female  / mixed? Sorry for soo many questions. I'm just curious aswell. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [**Urusei Yatsura 2: Beautiful Dreamer**](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1921/Urusei_Yatsura_Movie_2:_Beautiful_Dreamer). I highly recommend **Urusei Yatsura**, but I would urge you to watch the TV series before even beginning to think about enjoying this movie... or not. This movie kinda stands on its own, but not knowing the characters is kinda sad.

The most convincing proof is [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wy8CWV0ki-A&t=2935), it starts right where the group lifts off the planet and they see what you described.

Here is part of [the synopsis from IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088334/synopsis?ref_=ttpl_sa_2):

> However, when they get a ways above the city, everyone is shocked to see that the province of Tomobiki-cho is on a circular disc on the back of a turtle, floating through space. The group also zooms in under the disc, noting that there are two giant statues holding it up on the turtle's back: one of Onnsen-Mark, the other of Sakurambo, Sakura's uncle (who she noted had seemed to disappear recently).

Here is the fat dream man.

[image]

Here is the oddly shaped world and a statue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks a lot. So there is a series and then 2 movies?

Comment: 195 episode series, 12 OVAs, and 6 films. All this and the animation still didn't adapt all the manga chapters. I think all of the films except #5 are original stories. It's great IMO, but might be too old for the typical anime fan.